# WooCommerce SagePay Direct Payment Gateway - Error on checkout

Tags: e-commerce, woocommerce, opayo

When logged in as admin checkout fails and doesn't output any errors, works fine when logged out or logged in as a customer.

When putting WordPress into debug mode i get the following PHP Notices:

> Notice: Undefined variable: cards in
>   /wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php
>   on line 155
>
> Notice: Undefined property: DS_Sagepay_Direct::$validated in
>   /wp-content/plugins/sagepay-direct-for-woocommerce-payment-gateway/ds-sagepay-direct.php
>   on line 476

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The checkout would fail due to the DS_Sagepay_Direct::$validated variable not being set when using the pay page. This was a bug with WooCommerce 1.6 and has been fixed in 2.0.